# How to grep an eternal string coming from STDIN

Tags: grep, random, tr

Using bash i'm trying to grep a string coming from /dev/urandom something like this:

```
tr -cd '[:lower:]' < /dev/urandom | grep -o 'test'
```

Also tried:

```
tr -cd '[:lower:]' < /dev/urandom | grep -o 'test' | head -1
```

I guess `grep` keeps waiting for `tr` to finish, because even redirecting the output to a file like `> /tmp/testfile` nothing is written to the file.

However if parsed to `head` before `grep`, it works

```
tr -cd '[:lower:]' < /dev/urandom | head -c 10000 | grep -o 'test'
```

Is there a way to make it work while stdin is still running?, and if not, why is this behavior from `grep`, not to give an output if input hasn't finished?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You're reading a stream of random characters, and expecting to see some particular fixed string, why?

Comment: A `grep -o` able to search through lines of infinite length could probably be implemented with [pcre2partial](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2partial.html), but I'm not aware of any grep-like tool making use of that.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, [`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) processes lines:

> The *grep* utility shall search the input files, selecting lines matching one or more patterns

Your input doesn’t contain any newline characters, so `grep` waits endlessly for a line to check against the pattern specified in its arguments.

`head -c 10000` fixes that by “ending” the line after 10,000 characters. Another solution is to allow newlines in the input, as [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532033/how-to-grep-an-eternal-string-coming-from-stdin#comment984714_532033) by [mosvy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/308316/mosvy):

```
tr -cd '[:lower:]\n' < /dev/urandom | grep -o 'test'
```