# Is it possible to grep from a stream that has no new line?

Tags: grep, newlines

When running this code:

```
while true; do printf "Match Unmatch\n"; sleep 1s; done | grep -o "Match"
```

in a terminal, `grep` finds the word `Match`. I get the output:

```
Match
Match
Match
...
```

However, when I run the following code:

```
while true; do printf "Match Unmatch"; sleep 1s; done | grep -o "Match"
```

then `grep` seems to find nothing, at least it prints nothing. Is grep waiting for a newline that will never come? Is there some way of making grep, sed or similar tool capture matches in streams without the newline character?

Comment: How do you imagine this would work? If there's no newline then how can grep know when to start trying to find a match? If only 'Matc' has been piped to it for example and grep runs, it won't find any matches.

Comment: It match but try to read the whole line?

Comment: @JShorthouse Well, that is exactly what I want to know. Is there some way to make grep, or other similar tool, *not* wait for a newline before matching, or if it indeed does match, then *not* wait for a newline before writing the match to stdout? Or is that a flawed proposition? If so, what fundamentals am I failing to grasp?

Comment: - grep waits for the flush. - What version of grep? do you have a --line-buffered? as in`grep --line-buffered "Match"`.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, It does have --line-buffered.

Comment: @Rinzwind Its GNU grep v 3.1 according to the man page.

Comment: @Rinzwind `--line-buffered` is irrelevant here since grep is printing to a terminal. It doesn't affect how grep reads input.

Comment: Please read my [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532033/how-to-grep-an-eternal-string-coming-from-stdin#comment984734_532033) to an eerily similar [problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532033/308316). __tl;dr;__ this is not possible with the regular grep or any grep-like tools I know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep mainly looks for lines that contain a match for the given pattern. Depending on the pattern, it may or may not be possible to determine whether a line matches without looking at the whole line. With `grep Match`, this is possible, but with `grep 'Match$'`, it isn't. With `grep -o Match`, grep could print `Match` as soon as it sees it, but with `grep -E -o '(Match)+'`, if grep has read `MatchMa`, it doesn't know whether `tch` will follow or not.

Grep does not implement the special cases where it would be possible to write some output before seeing a whole line. (I think it doesn't implement *any* such special case, but I'm not completely sure: GNU grep has several modes depending on the pattern that behave somewhat differently.) It just reads one whole line before trying to match.

If there's a character that's never appears in matching text and that always (or at least often) appear between matches, transform this character into a newline. (Or into a null byte and use `grep -z`.)

```
while true; do printf "Match Unmatch"; sleep 1s; done | stdbuf -o0 tr ' ' '\n' | grep -o "Match"
```

Note the use of `stdbuf -o0` to prevent `tr` from buffering its output. And if you pipe the output of grep, you'll need that for grep as well, or use `grep --line-buffered`. (`--line-buffered` buffers the *output* of grep; it has no impact on how grep reads input, and it's on by default when grep is printing to a terminal.)